# What is the difference between restart and deploy: restart in docker-compose v.3?

Tags: docker-compose, restart

I understand that from docker-compose version 3 it is possible to use restart policies with more parameters as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
```

However, in many examples, here and in other forums, they still show the following form:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    restart: on-failure [3]
```

Is it possible to do it both ways from version 3?

It is not clear from the documentation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it states that whatever is declared in "deploy" is ignored by "docker-compose up" and "docker-compose run". In this case, I use "docker-compose up -d", so I understand I should declare it as follows.

```
version: "3"
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    restart: on-failure [3]
```

Both ways are valid, but it depends on how the docker-compose is executed, is that the difference?